# Redirect to another view on the same taskflow programatically on ADF

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, oracle-adf, adf-task-flow

I have one taskflow and have two views like this image:

[image: Example of two views]

I have a button to go there, but I don't need to click the button. I need to redirect programmatically to another view with calling the action.

How to call it, because I am using JSFF as a page?

If I use this method:

```
       FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   UIViewRoot root = fctx.getViewRoot();
   //client Id of button includes naming container like id of region. 
   RichCommandButton button = 
       (RichCommandButton) root.findComponent("cb1");
   ActionEvent actionEvent = new ActionEvent(button);
   actionEvent.queue();
   }
```

I get an error like can't find the component. If I use page template id I also get an error like the compiler can't find the component.

Do you have another method to solve this, or can you fix it if I get wrong find component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have use "URL view" and redirect it to your path :[image]

Answer (score 1):

For such case i use this code:

```
public static void navigateTo(String redirect) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler nh = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    nh.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, redirect);
}
```

where redirect param is a name of flow case rule.